# flot not displaying gson data

Tags: javascript, json, gson, flot

Code below results in graph with no data series being plotted,
Actual data being loaded

```
rob@workLaptop:~$ cat /path/to/files/data/myFile.txt 
1,1
2,1
3,1
```

Java ..

```
import java.util.Vector;

    public class Dataset {

    private String name;
    private Vector<GraphPoint> points;

    public Dataset(String nameTemp){

        this.name = nameTemp;
        this.points = new Vector<GraphPoint>();
    }
}
```

Send `Vector<Dataset>` from servlet to javascript using AJAX, data is serialized using `response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(datasets));`

javascript ..

```
$(".body").append('<div id="content"><div class="demo-container"><div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div></div></div>');
var datasets = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
//alert(xmlhttp.responseText);          
var plotarea = $("#placeholder");
$.plot(plotarea, [datasets[0].points, datasets[1].points]);
```

`alert(xmlhttp.responseText);` output ..

```
[
    {"name":"myFile.txt",
    "points":[
        {"timestamp":30,"value":100},
        {"timestamp":31,"value":101},
        {"timestamp":32,"value":110}
    ]},
    {"name":"anotherFile.txt",
    "points":[
        {"timestamp":1382987630,"value":200},
        {"timestamp":1382987631,"value":201},
        {"timestamp":1382987632,"value":205}
    ]}
]
```

Comment: Your data is not in the correct format see here: https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format.

Comment: hm, so `Dataset` needs to be redefined? perhaps `private Vector<GraphPoint> points;` is not a good method to represent the data series

Comment: No, GraphPoint is somesort of specific java object. It looks like the JSON convertor is doing it's best and converting it to a javascript object with properties "timestamp" and "value", but flot's not going to understand that.  Try `private Vector<Vector<int>>`, you need something that jsonify into `[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],etc...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the right format, for each series in the graph create `Dataset` object

```
public class Dataset {

    private String name;
    private Vector<Vector<Integer>> points;
```

Read series data from each file into `Vector<Dataset>`

```
File[] files = finder("/path/to/files/" + request.getParameter("data") + "/");

    Vector<Dataset> datasets = new Vector<Dataset>();

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){

        datasets.add(readData(files[i]));
    }
```

Send json data to client

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(datasets));

System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(datasets));
```

System output ..

`[{"name":"myFile.txt","points":[[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]]},{"name":"anotherFile.txt","points":[[0,10],[2,20],[5,50]]}]`

```
private Dataset readData(File file){

    Dataset dataset = new Dataset(file.getName());

    try{
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){

            Vector<Integer> points = new Vector<Integer>();

            points.add(Integer.parseInt(strLine.split(",")[0]));
            points.add(Integer.parseInt(strLine.split(",")[1]));

            dataset.addset(points);
        }

        in.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dataset;
}

private File[] finder(String dirName) {

    File dir = new File(dirName);

    return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            return filename.endsWith(".txt");
        }
    });
}
```